# An Android "exploration" app that marks in a specific color each location where I have previously been?

Tags: france, paris, mobile-apps

I love exploring my city, however keeping track of which street I have already seen is a hassle.

Would any of you know

I can only find application that suggest point of interest around me

Comment: Can you tell us for which system you want it? iOS, Android, pure webapp? Would you be happy with a social web site where or you prefer a "real" application?

Comment: @DamienClauzel OP specifies Android in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried that one but it looks like it will do the job: 
[GPS Map Explorer Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lukasheidenreich.gpsmapexplorer_lite)

PS: I am not at all linked with that app or the guy/team behind!

Comment: ooh, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Set it as answered so! Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in Italy for a week I used the Digitourist app. This app shows you everything you can do in the surroundings. I recommend this app for people that like to visit activities and attractions. This link will directly send you to their website; www.Digitourist.com